# how can i increase the number of recent work spaces?

Tags: visual-studio-code

my VS code shows only the last 4 workspaces i had open.

is there a way to increase this to 10 or more?

I've googled and searched through settings but can't find this.

- not sure if they are time or # based, but projects i had opened last week are no longer in this list

Comment: I show 5 for me and I should have only 5.  I don't think there is any setting that modifies it.

Comment: sometimes i see 5 also.. but my point is that projects i had opened last week or 2 weeks ago disappear from the list. not sure if its time or # based.